# Transform doesn't work with animation

Tags: ios, swift3, calayer, catransform3d

I'm trying to set up a `CALayer` to increase in width at the bottom of my viewcontroller by using `CATransform3DMakeScale`. I can get the layer to scale just fine, but when I try to apply the transformation through an animation, the layer transforms without any animation.

```
let progressBar1 = CALayer()

override func viewDidAppear() {
    progressBar1.bounds = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 1, height: 5)
    progressBar1.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 600)
    progressBar1.backgroundColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
    view.layer.addSublayer(progressBar1)
    extendBar1()
}

func extendBar1(){
    let transform1 = CATransform3DMakeScale(30, 1, 0)
    let anim = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform")
    anim.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
    anim.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards
    anim.toValue = NSValue(caTransform3D:transform1)
    anim.duration = 10.00
    progressBar1.add(anim, forKey: "transform")
}
```

I also tried the following with `CATransaction` but I get the same result

```
func extendBar3(){

    let transform1 = CATransform3DMakeScale(30, 1, 0)

    CATransaction.begin()
    CATransaction.setAnimationDuration(7.0)
    progressBar1.transform = transform1
    CATransaction.commit()
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The chief remaining problem is this line:

```
    let transform1 = CATransform3DMakeScale(30, 1, 0)
```

Change the `0` to a `1`.

(The result may still not be the animation you want, precisely, but at least you should see something — as long as `(0,600)` is not off the screen entirely, of course.)